# Angular 1.x Iframe with html content

Tags: angular, iframe

I do have html content comes from the API.
How do I display it with iframe ?

Something like 
`{ ..., template: "<h3 style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; ..." ...}`

Please provide demo if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more information with your question? At the current state, it's unclear what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pipe for iframe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

And in the component

```
@NgModule({
   declarations : [
     ...
     SafePipe
   ],
})
```

HTML

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="url | safe"></iframe>
```

You can refer this [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uifk3dxf7vwKJsUFb0d9?p=preview)

For Angular1.x [**Plunker**](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/xibawo)

Comment: Thanks, can it be same with angular 1 ?

Comment: @BHARGAV It is for angular 2 or higher

Comment: How can I do the same with Angular 1.x

Comment: I've seen that link before but it is not up to my expectation, as I said, It comes from the API which have array objects with JSON html.